# Can javascript get the SSID of the current WiFi connection?

Tags: javascript, browser, network-programming

I need to get the SSID of the currently connected WiFi Network (if it is wifi). Is this possible?

I saw something on it here (http://www.w3.org/TR/system-info-api/#network), but I can't seem to get the code to run. Is there a library I need to import or is this just planned implementations?

I'm writing a phonegap application and need to know whether I should connect to a server locally or if I need to go remotely.

Thanks

Comment: It's a working draft - the very first stage of the W3C process. I don't know whether anyone has implemented any of it.

Comment: in terms of popular browsers alone, no, not possible. Perhaps cordova tunnels an OS API, but i've not seen anything like that. You can get connection info in some browsers, but that only indicates [off, paid, and wide], not connection specifics.

Comment: So my only option here is to either build a plug-in for it or to find one that is already built. Does anyone know of one that might be able to do this?

Comment: I found one for Android under the MIT license if anyone is interested: https://github.com/HondaDai/PhoneGap-WifiInfoPlugin. Thanks HondaDai.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible as of this time. However PhoneGap does let you build plug-ins that will accomplish this task.

There is currently one available from HondaDai under the MIT license located at https://github.com/HondaDai/PhoneGap-WifiInfoPlugin.

** and it works beautifully. After I figured out how it works. His example on how to get the SSID that shows wifi.SSID as a variable is incorrect. It is actually wifi.activity.SSID as there are two JSON objects in the return and I wanted to access the one title activity.